# cakephp flash error not working

Tags: validation, cakephp, redirect

i've created a login in system where an activated user can log in but a user who's account hasnt been activated wont be able to log in. The problem is that no flash message is outputted when the user tries to log in with a deactivated account, so a user wouldn't know why the page keeps refreshing on the login page.

heres my login function

```
if ($this->request->is('post')){
    if ($this->request->data['User']['password'] == 'qazwsx'){
    if ($this->Auth->login()){
    $username = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
     if (0 === $this->User->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('activated'=>1,'username'=> $username)))) {
         $this->Session->setFlash('Sorry, your account is not validated yet.');
         $this->redirect($this->referer());
    }

        $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect('eboxs/home')); 
        }   
    } 
    else {

        $this->Session->setFlash('Username or password is incorrect');
    }
    }else{
    $this->Session->setFlash('Welcome, please login');
    }


}
```

I havent included my view cause so far with flash messages i havent had to call them

Comment: is your logic definitely working? do a `echo 'working'; exit;` before the redirect and login with a deactivated account to ensure. then, check the page the user was on actually outputs flash messages (as you are using `$this->referer()`)

Comment: when doing that it takes me to a new page that just says working

Comment: i also tried putting this inside the referer code 

die('this is a test');, same thing happened

Comment: OK that means that your condition is being triggered. So now - are you actually outputting the flash message in your layout, or wherever it is the user gets redirected to? It's being set; but are you display it? You said `I haven't included my view...`

Comment: Like Ross said, you probably need `$this->Session->flash();` in your layout. You can also use DebugKit (https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) to make sure it makes it in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Weird Authentification way you're doing there.

Like you've been already told in the comments, check, wherever the user is redirected ($this->redirect), there is a

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

in that view.

Also with that method, the user is logged in anyway. You've to manually log out that user again, before you show him the flash message / redirect him.

You can also just write:

```
<?php
  ...
  $this->Auth->scope = array('User.activated' => 1);

  if ($this->Auth->login()) {
    // logged-in logic
  } else {
    // not logged-in logic
  }
?>
```

This would save you some lines of code.